# ASP.NET ValidatorOnChange being fired on a DropDownList even though CausesValidation is by default false

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, requiredfieldvalidator

The use case here is that a dropdownlist that has AutoPostBack set to true, which updates the other items on the page. However the same dropdownlist is also part of required item in the ValidationGroup when submit button is clicked.

The problem we're facing is that when the dropdownlist changes, the ValidatorOnChange is triggered and therefore shows the error briefly before the postback refreshes the page.

The fix we're planning to do is to remove the ValidatorOnChange function for the dropdownlist, but this seems like a weird hack, so we're wondering if anyone has any other suggestions.

Here's a very simple list that demonstrate the problem:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    private void OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateList.Visible = test.SelectedValue == "1";
        updateList2.Visible = test.SelectedValue == "2";
    }

    private void OnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {

        }
    }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="test" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnChange">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Test" Value="-1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Test 1" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Test 2" Value="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Test 3" Value="3" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DropDownListValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="test"
            ErrorMessage="Please select" InitialValue="-1" ValidationGroup="testGroup" />
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="updateList" Visible="false" />
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="updateList2" Visible="false" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="testSubmit" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="testGroup"
            OnClick="OnSubmit" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you paste the markup for the same

Comment: Also, just in case someone question that CausesValidation may be true by default, here's the MSDN doc saying CausesValidation is default to false on all ListControl.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.causesvalidation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following jquery script block should work for you. disabling validation using `ValidatorEnable()`  when selecting an item from Dropdownlist will do the trick

here i bind the change handler with the onchange client side event of the dropdownlist

```
$("#<%=test.ClientID %>").change(function(){
    ValidatorEnable(DropDownListValidator2, false);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but this actually disables the validation completely and the error notification won't show up when the button is pressed. It'll have to be a special case to disable/enable based on the InitialValue set in the RequiredFieldValidator. However I'm not sure if this is better than simply remove ValidatorOnChange event handler from the control.

Comment: @bluefox have you tested it. it will only disables the validation the time when you do postback from dropdownlist not from your submit button because we only binded the dropdown change handler to the script and not the button click. note that you fired validation when only first option is selected and it fires right on button click

Comment: this is the thing came to my mind i don't think there is other way of doing so on the client side AFAIK

Comment: Ah right I see, because the DDL causes a postback, so ValidatorEnable will be reset back to true when the page returns. However, this requires control to be part of the update panel or being regenerated. This won't work if the ValidatorEnable is not reset for the control.